# Is it possible to call API's from the provided url using curl

Tags: php, web-services

I've to call API's from a given url in my code. I try to call url using curl.
now  I want to use APi's provided by this url in my code.

Comment: @Beginner Can you elaborate on what API you are wanting to use?

Comment: the website which i am going to call in my code has some web service API's. i want to use this API's in my code.Is it possible using curl?

Comment: Just repeating the question without adding details doesn't help. All one can do right now is answer the general question *"is it possible to access APIs using cURL"*, which, yes, it is.

Comment: Lacking any further details, here is documentation for using cURL to talk to the Yahoo APIs: http://developer.yahoo.com/php/

Comment: Many sites that offer an API also offer free php / python / etc classes to interact with it. You might want to check the documentation for the API in question carefully, this work may already be done for you :)

Comment: By web service, do you mean SOAP, or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

A web service API typically just communicates over the HTTP protocol. You send some specific requests and receive answers in a certain format, the same thing your browser does with websites. cURL is a great tool to do so.

The specifics will really depend on the API in question, you should study whatever documentation they provide for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with APIS that are based on xml and support the soap protocol a better idea will be just to use soap then curl (less code needed)